# Why does my Swagger UI try to access non http content when loaded on https?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, swagger-2.0

I'm using AWS:ALB, so I have a rule which forwards all traffic to a specific target group. When working locally, I am able to access the swagger ui page with no issues since HTTP. When deployed to AWS with a HTTPS ALB, I see it trying to load some HTTP content; which of course get blocked by browser.

Error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://alb.com/alert/docs/swagger-ui.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://alb.com/swagger-resources/configuration/ui'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I have the following in my config in my project so that swagger ui can load under /alert/docs/swagger-ui.html:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class DocumentationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/alert/docs/v2/api-docs", "/v2/api-docs");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/alert/docs/configuration/ui", "/configuration/ui");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/alert/docs/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/alert/docs/swagger-resources/configuration/security", "/swagger-resources/configuration/security");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/alert/docs/configuration/security", "/configuration/security");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/alert/docs/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/alert/docs/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    }
}
```

Am I missing any configuration which causes this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SpringBoot you can add this:

```
server:
    tomcat:
        remote-ip-header: x-forwarded-for
        protocol-header: x-forwarded-proto`
```

to your application.yaml or application.properties.
More details available here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-security.html#howto-enable-https